# What is this strange and possibly old white 2x4 brick?

Tags: part-identification

I've got 6 or 8 white 2x4 bricks. But they seem to be rather old as there is a "Pat. Pending" on it and also a "C5".

They also have one small hole on each of its sides (but none on top) and the interior is transparent.

Does anyone know from which set this comes?

[image: view from underside]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is [Brick, Modified 2 x 4 with Wheels Holder, Trans-Clear Bottom](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=7049b). White colored version was included in [77 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=7049b&colorID=1&in=A).

Comment: ...and they go together with [wheels like these](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=7039).

Comment: @noughtnaut this brick is not limited to wheels like these. There are more elements that go together.

Comment: Yup. That was intended merely as an example for people who've never seen this brick before.